# Reply to someone who says "you are the best"

Tags: phrase-request

Someone appreciated my work and wrote "You are the best, thanks."

How should I reply to this as a courtesy?

Comment: I disagree with closing the question. An important point, for both native-speakers (see the answers) and learners, is that while various replies have different levels of formality, an important distinction is in how much work you are implying you did for the person thanking you. "No problem" is less formal than "It was nothing", but the common point is that both imply that what you did was either part of your expected duties/behavior or took little effort on your part. Other phrases acknowledge that you were inconvenienced but gladly so. This isn't just opinion.

Answer (score 6):

### It actually matters how you would like to respond. Do you want to be formal or informal.

Below i wanted explain how @David's answer made me feel.

### -No problem (Very commonly used, Informal)

This is far from being formal and totaly counts as **informal** but people who uses English as their second language **might sometimes use this as a formal** reply. In street slang also can be followed by friendly namings (dude, bro, man..etc) to show how close you feel.

### -Glad I could help (Friendly, Informal)

It is a response when you are **experiencing pleasure, joy, or delight while helping**. You take it as a mission and overcome a lot problems for the one that you feel important to you with pleasure. This is also leaves the speaker in an expectation for further conversation.

### -My pleasure (Rarely used, Formal)

It is a response that is much **more polite than "You're welcome"**.
You enjoy helping him/her/them and helping them also works out for you as well. It's actually **formal** but you can also see it is commonly used between close friends and family members in an informal way.

### -You're welcome (Very Formal)

It's mostly used as conversation ending sentence.
Seriously, it takes 1-2 seconds to finish the sentence and felts like you are in a hurry and **don't care much about his/her/their appreciation.**

### -It was nothing (Cordial, Somewhat informal)

Reminiscent of the Spanish phrase ***de nada***, this one might be especially appropriate when you want to humbly dismiss high praise, such as "***You're the best.***" Very similar to ***no problem***, though less common.

Comment: I liked this answer so much I decided to add one more. Feel free to delete it (i.e. do a rollback) if you'd rather stick with your Original 4.

Comment: @J.R. no i really like it. "It was nothing" is a rarely used but a very good answer. While saying it there is a little sarcasm and politeness.

Comment: I say "no problem" all the time and *dude* never follows it.

Comment: I'd have said *"You're welcome"* is much more informal than *"My pleasure"*, and that *"No problem"* is by far the most informal of all these.

Comment: @horatio as i said and J.R. corrected "often" followed by dude not by everyone and every time. Feel free to improve.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i agree with "No problem" it's the most informal answer but here is the situation; People who uses English language as their second language are not seeing the fact; it is informal! 
Most of the time i see people on business meetings does this and thinks it's a formal reply.

Comment: @FumbleFingers for further understanding think of a meeting where people show their product and you liked one of them but it's not fully solves your problem and you requested a specialized version of it. At that point you get an answer like this: "No problem! We can remodel it the way you like." It sounds formal at that point cause you just met with that seller.

Comment: @Berker: In your answer, you yourself said that *"No problem!"* is ***often followed*** by *"Dude"*, so clearly you recognise that native speakers habitually use the expression in ***informal*** contexts. If non-native speakers use it in formal contexts that's up to them - native speakers will [make allowance](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+allowances+for). But it doesn't change the fact that it's essentially an informal usage, even if non-native speakers fail to recognise this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess you are right! Fixing it now.

Comment: The phrase in question "You are the best, thanks.", is itself informal, so it is natural to reply with an informal response as well.

Comment: @Berker: I still think your *formal...informal* rankings are bizarre. For example, checking Google Books for *You're welcome,* followed by either [*your Majesty*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you're+welcome+your+majesty%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) or [mate](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you're+welcome+mate%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) should be enough to prove that's an ***informal*** usage. Do the same with, say, *it was nothing* and you'll see the opposite bias (I think we can safely assume most people are relatively formal when speaking to "your Majesty").

Comment: @FumbleFingers well it might be bizarre but as i mentioned before i showed what "i" understand and i am open for improvements, tough i should also point you to the wiktionary where the word's state more reliable http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_are_welcome

Comment: @Berker: Don't believe everything you read on Wiktionary! Actually, I think you've just misunderstood that entry. It's not that *"You **are** welcome"* is "formal" in any meaningful sense - except when contrasted with the contracted form *"You're welcome"*. In practice the non-contracted version is simply *rare, unusual*, not *formal*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i see what you mean now. I really didn't know that and if you can also provide some examples about it's different usages that would be great. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @Berker: I thought the links in my comment 3 above this covered formal/informal contexts for *You are/You're welcome*. If you want more, here are 3 for [*"You are welcome, sir", (he](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you+are+welcome+sir+he%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) said/replied/etc.)*. Compare that to [About 3,670 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you're+welcome+sir+he%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for the "contracted, **informal**" version.

Comment: ...also note that the "uncontracted" version is to say the least "unusual" today. It mainly occurs in *older* texts, where the speaker means it more literally (*"I am welcoming you into my house"*, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers for future reference make some fixations on this please.. :D

Answer (score 4):

A few common responses to compliments are "you're welcome", "no problem", "my pleasure" or "glad I could help".

Comment: Am I right when I think that _you are welcome_ is general polite reply for any situation while _glad I could help_ is used more when some more interaction was made before (you discussed the problem in detail, you actually know that it was really important for the one who wrote you)?

Comment: @MasterPJ - I'll bet I could come up with an exception if I thought hard enough, but, 99% of the time, that's a safe guideline to follow.

Comment: @ J.R. : yes definitely, exceptions are there!!!

Comment: Only use *Glad I could help* when you actually *helped* and you are happy that you were able to do so (or you wish them to think you are).  You can use *you're welcome* when you've been thanked for anything- a gift, a kindness, providing help, etc.

Comment: @ Jim : I agree with you...

Answer (score 1):

> The best of all is " My Pleasure".

because it suggests that you accepted the opportunity and tried your best to help and solve the issue and gave the best solution that really worked for the person.  So, it works for both, accepting the challenges as well as replying politely and accept the appreciation....

Comment: nice touch there but if you don't want the guy follow you like a little kitten you should avoid using this. Cause you may helped for once and doesn't want to be his/her/their life coach. If you know what i mean..

Comment: @Berker Yuceer : Can you please explain me this ? Because, I don't think "my pleasure" asks the person to ask for help again from me only..

Comment: Not directly but if you had many problems that you can't solve alone and you know a guy who gets "pleasure" from solving your problems i bet you would go to him again and again.

Comment: @ Berker Yuceer : Amazing!!! ha ha ha ... nice thinking.I never thought in that direction, But, I think that depends on  personal opinion...

Comment: exactly but you know human factor always messes up with calculations..

Answer (score 0):

I would simply respond with "You're welcome.", which is a common and polite reply to being thanked.

Comment: I don't think "You're welcome" works everywhere because when someone is in deep difficulty and you help him out, then replying "You're welcome" to his thanks shows that indirectly you are asking that person to be in difficulty again!!!! saying "My pleasure" shows that you readily accepted the opportunity and tried to help at your best and it worked out..

Comment: @Sweet72- please explain why saying *You're welcome* shows indirectly that you are asking that the person get into trouble again.  This is simply not true.

Comment: I think like Jim, I am mystified by @Sweet72's comment!

Answer (score 0):

Replies to "Thanks" is given as per situation:

1) If someone is in difficulty and you help him/ her out, then rather than "You're Welcome" , my pleasure works best if it's a formal situation. In informal situation, "No problem" or "It's OK" will suit the purpose..

2) When you want someone to visit you again, you can say " You're Welcome".

3) In friendly terms, if you don't want to accept thanks , then the reply can be " No Mention", "no problem".

4) My pleasure can be said when you really feel good to help someone or you like to help them, wish them and it's ok if they don't ask for your help again..

> The best of all is " My Pleasure".

because it suggests that you accepted the opportunity and tried your best to help and solve the issue and gave the best solution that really worked for the person.  So, it works for both, accepting the challenges as well as replying politely and accept the appreciation....